# Why does this function satisfy $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial z^2}=0 ?$

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I am working on a mock exam for Partial differential equations, and the exam claims that the following two functions

$p(z,t) = \frac{1}{2\lambda} e^{-\lambda z + \lambda^2 t / 2}$

and

$p(z,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} e^{-z^2/(2t)}$

satisfy the equation

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial z^2}=0 ?$

But I don't think they do.

For the first one, my "solution" was to note that:

$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}p(z,t)$
and $\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial z^2} = \lambda^2p(z,t)$

Hence, the equation does not hold.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you think that $\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} = -\frac{\lambda^2}{2}p$ and not $\frac{\lambda^2}{2}p$?

Comment: Do you know that this PDE is the heat equation ?

Comment: No, I did not know. 
I was able to solve this problem (prove that they satisfy the heat equation) looking for heat equation and being more careful on the partial derivatives. 

Thank you both